# Every Xpage app I open in designer spews 1000s of java errors

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I just came back from MWLUG and started to open up some Xpages DBs to work on, when all of the sudden I am getting 1000s of errors like this:

[image]

I googled the issue and I believe it has something to do with the path of the org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins.

When I opened up the packages and looked at fixing an error I got this:

[image]

The problem is that I do not know what the correct setting for this should be, or how to fix it. The apps run fine, but obviously something is wrong.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Bryan

==================================================

I may know more about the problem. In designer when I go to File==>Application==Application Management this is what I see:

[image]

A different install has several components under it.

I updated my designer and client and admin to 9.0.1 FP4 last week. That is the last thing I remember doing before this messed up (along with installing the Debug Toolbar).

How can I fix my designer install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange indeed, you should check your hard drive for bad sectors.

Looks like a broken DDE in general. The plugin XML file maybe broken so the app manager doesn't show you the plugins installed. Therefor I assume DDE starts very quickly, right? Because nothing is loaded. 
I had this before and my "solution" was:

- de-install DDE and Fixpacks
- delete workspace folder
- re-install DDE and Fixpacks
- re-install plugins ad setup workig sets

This is a pity but at least you get a clean install. You don't have to delete everything (e.g. the DATA folder)

Comment: Oliver, this is good advice, but how can I de-install only DDE?

Comment: Just go to system settings, programs and features, remove IBM Notes

Comment: But this will uninstall the notes client and the admin client too. Is that the only way to do this?

Comment: Exactly, you have to reinstall this package again afterwards, but no worries: if you don't kill the DATA folder everything is in place again.